# how to notify users about new theme updates?

Tags: themes

how to add notifications to wordpress theme so users can know there is new theme update?

is there code to do that?

and many thanks in advance.

Comment: How are you releasing the updates? If it's on wordpress.org, you don't need any code. For other platforms they will often provide you the necessary code. If you're doing it 100% yourself then it's much more complicated.

Comment: @Jacob Peattie  thanks so much for reply. yes, I am doing it 100% myself. so what should I do, please?